# Updating the support-v4 library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I cant update the support-v4 library on android studio, current version on my project is 25.2.0 and i want to update it to 27.1.1 i tried going with

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4-25.2.0'
```

but it says failed to resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing to resolve because instead of v4-25.2.0 should be v4:25.2.0

**Replace**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4-25.2.0'
```

**by**

`implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'`

Comment: Worked! Thanks! :)

Comment: Done, i was waiting for the 3 minutes time :)